# I have to get OffsetDateTime from a string

Tags: java, timestamp, java-time, offsetdatetime, datetimeparseexception

String is in this format - "2021-07-13 05:22:18.712"

I tried using this code to parse it.
`OffsetDateTime parsedDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-07-13 05:22:18.712");`

But i keep getting this error -
org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-07-13 05:22:18.712' could not be parsed at index 10.

How do i make it work? Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: "2021-07-13 05:22:18.712" does not have an offset in it. What offset do you want your `parsedDateTime` to have?

Comment: What did your search turn up? Was [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decide on a time zone (or at least on an offset, but time zone is usually the correct means). And then you need to use a formatter that defines the format that you are trying to parse:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

With this formatter it’s a pretty simple operation:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    String input = "2021-07-13 05:22:18.712";
    
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, FORMATTER)
            .atZone(zone)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output from the example snippet is:

> 2021-07-13T05:22:18.712+05:30

Since as @Sweeper noted in a comment your string does not contain UTC offset nor time zone, parse it into a `LocalDateTime` first. The `Local` in some java.time class names means *without time zone or UTC offset*. Then convert into a `ZonedDateTime` in the intended time zone and further into the desired type, `OffsetDateTime`.

If you want to use the default time zone of the JVM, set `zone` to `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. Be aware that the default time zone may be changed at any time from another part of your program or another program running in the same JVM, so this is fragile.

### Possible shortcuts

My formatter is wordy because I wanted to reuse as much as I could from built-in formatters. If you don’t mind building the formatter by hand from a pattern, you may use:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ROOT);
```

Or even shorter, you may hand substitute the space in your string with a `T` to obtain ISO 8601 format and then parse into a `LocalDateTime` without specifying any formatter at all.

### What went wrong in your code?

The exception message you got is trying to be helpful:

> But i keep getting this error -
> org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-07-13
> 05:22:18.712' could not be parsed at index 10.

Index 10 in your string is where the space between date and time is. The one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse` method expects ISO 8601 format, like `2021-07-13T05:22:18.712+05:30`, so with a `T` to denote the start of the time part and with a UTC offset at the end. The absence of the `T` caused your exception. Had you fixed that, you would have got another exception because of the missing UTC offset.

### Link

[Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thank you so much @ole V.V , this helped a lott. was not expecting this much detail. can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to check the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

It indicates parse need to go with a date format such as 2007-12-03**T**10:15:30 **+01:00**.

You date is missing a "T", "2021-07-13 05:22:18.712". Hence it did not go well, counting it from index 0, it's character at 10.

If you need to parse *2021-07-13T05:22:18.712*, you will still get error. An error Text '2021-07-13T05:22:18.712' could not be parsed at index 23. Which is the problem of miliseconds.

So a big round to go:

```
//Format to date
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
//Format to new string
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"); 
java.util.Date date1=simpleDateFormat.parse("2021-07-13 05:22:18.712");
String newDate = formatter.format(date1);

//finally.    
OffsetDateTime parsedDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(newDate);
```

Comment: Very strongly discouraged. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. And OPI is already using java.time.

Comment: BTW it’s also not correct. I tried with the string `2021-07-13 12:27:38.667` and expected `2021-07-13T12:27:38.667+02:00` in my time zone.  Instead I got `2021-07-13T00:27:38+02:00`. It’s 12 hours 667 milliseconds off.

Comment: But the explanation of what was wrong or missing is good and almost correct. :-)

Comment: Ole V. V., yeah forgotten it's 24H. fixed.

Comment: But i agree your answer is much more precise and right, yours should be an accepted answer. It's also non Thread safe with this method of SimpleDateFormat I'm using.
I got left out using java.time, but it's great that i'm learning this too. Thanks for the info.